# OpenMP4 - Why does calling a function multiple times makes it faster

Tags: openmp

So I'm currently learning openmp4.

What I experienced is that if I call a function a 2nd time it will get significantly faster.
The omp block is inside of this function.

In my example the 1st call takes 5 seconds and the 2nd only 0,3s.
I am using the intel-icc with an Intel Xeon Phi(60cores 240Threads).

Could someone please explain why this is happening?

Comment: The first time you call code with OpenMP it has to do some initialization.  For performance testing I usually call OpenMP once before profiling the code (I call this warming up OpenMP).  This is a reasonable thing to do if you will call the function several times.  You can call the time for the first call the cold time and all calls after that the warm time.

Comment: 5 s vs. 0.3 s is pretty extreme so it's unlikely the initialization I was referring to would account for that.

Comment: Initialising the Phi context is a very costly operation in terms of time. Recent MPSS versions improve things a bit but the first call is still quite expensive. That's normal and nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is due to the OpenMP threading initialization. The creation of the threading team, and initializing each thread, etc.. This in fact is an expensive procedure.

I don't know what your code looks like, but this can also be the effect of caching. During first time, the mic will start caching the needed data. The second time: the data will already be cached and ready. But I can't confirm this until I see the code.